# 2.2 static-content deploy generates extra themes

Tags: theme, magento2.2, theme-fallback, static-content-deploy

Since version 2.2, static-content:deploy for a theme will generate themes not specified using the *--theme* flag.
So before in 2.1.x I would generate a theme for 3 languages and get exactly 3 themes. Now I get 12.

Is there a setting I am missing or is it a new "feature"?

The command I am running it with is:

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme My/theme de_DE en_US fr_FR -f
```

Comment: could you show your command?

Comment: its create extra theme because your current theme depends on luma theme

Comment: I figured so, but in 2.1.x it didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I thought Luma was required and this issue vexed me also. So I reworked my Theme from blank and specifically did not depend on, use, mention, call out Luma in any way. And it was still being generated. I poured over everything I could find and this works for me:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --exclude-theme="Magento/luma"`